# Checking Updates from inside the App itself

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

Hello friends i am following this [link](http://www.pedrolamas.com/2013/07/24/checking-for-updates-from-inside-a-windows-phone-app/) to implementing checking for updates from inside the app.But i am not getting it implemented,I have expand the request and i think there is problem in its content.

problem is this it is not able to get updated version.

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(url); // here i checked it on applying breakpoints 

private Task<Version> GetUpdatedVersion()
{
    var cultureInfoName = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name;
var url = string.Format("http://marketplaceedgeservice.windowsphone.com/v8/catalog/apps/{0}?os={1}&cc={2}&oc=&lang={3}​",
    GetManifestAttributeValue("ProductID"),
    Environment.OSVersion.Version,
    cultureInfoName.Substring(cultureInfoName.Length - 2).ToUpperInvariant(),
    cultureInfoName);

var request = WebRequest.Create(url);

return Task.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, result =>
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);

    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        throw new WebException("Http Error: " + response.StatusCode);
    }

    using (var outputStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(outputStream))
        {
            reader.MoveToContent();

            var aNamespace = reader.LookupNamespace("a");

            reader.ReadToFollowing("entry", aNamespace);

            reader.ReadToDescendant("version");

            return new Version(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
        }
    }
}, null);
```

}

[image]

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Why don't you make it a synchronous process and debug it?

Comment: i have updated the question..check it..and i have to make this update async..

Comment: That's great, but doesn't it make sense to make it a synchronous process to get it working and make it easier to debug, allowing you to step by step going through it? Why not make it async when it *actually* works?

Comment: i have tried that already..Arran..but in the end it is not getting updated version

Comment: @Arran anyways there is no "synchronous" version of web api in windows phone, the only thing he could have done is not use Task but it will still be asynchronous using call back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some build in async extension for WebRequest no need to build your own. You can usdirectly use `WebResponse response= await request.GetResponseAsync();`
Concerning the real problem, I checked the store with the app id in the debug screenshot and [couldn't find any app coresponding to this app id](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appId=644388ce-b8ff-44b0-9c87-ae9cf26ff50d) so this id is probably the app id used for development and not the real app id of the app in the store, for it to work it need to be the real store id (when you really publish the app to the store it should work since the store will automatically update the app id). If you haven't publish the app to the store yet, to test the best is probably to just use the app id of another app for testing purpose.
Update:
Apparently it was the app id which was the problem. (like i said it need to be the app id of the published app in the store app not the local development one)

Comment: i have tried this with app id of app on store..and error is comming on adding the namesspace you have given ..threading does not exists in the namespace..

Comment: You are using the async bcl nuget package to support Task on wp7, right? Or are you on windows phone 8? (your post is tagged windows phone 7)

Comment: my app will target both platform..and actually the main problem is..the link is actually saying it is for both the platform..and working fine..then why i am getting problem ?

Comment: I just tested your code with an app id from random app from the store ("8bc8ee8a-03eb-42e9-9a5f-4dc6505d4030") and it was working so it is defenetively a pb with the app id you are using

Comment: you have followed the link exactly ?

Comment: thanks..benoit i think problem is with the productid plzz update your answer i will mark it right..

Comment: I copied your code and just replaced  GetManifestAttributeValue("ProductID") by 8bc8ee8a-03eb-42e9-9a5f-4dc6505d4030

Comment: Also if you want to use the already build in async method, you actually don't need the using, just directly use WebResponse response= await request.GetResponseAsync(); and i beleve this should compile